# RadDataForm style bugs when validation message appears

Tags: css, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm using **RadDataForm** with **NativeScript-Vue**. I made the following style:

```css
RadDataForm {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

DataFormEditorLabel {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

DataFormEditorCore {
  placeholder-color: #b8b8b8;
  padding: 5 10;
  border-width: 1;
  border-color: #b8b8b8;
  margin: 3 0;
  font-size: 16;
  text-align: left;
}

PropertyEditor {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

[image: screenshot]

When a validation message appears (like in the first field) the borders are gone. If I move the border properties from DataFormEditorCore to PropertyEditor, it works, but the validation message is inside the border too. What I want is to show the border around the field, but the validation message below it.

Comment: Could be an issue with their CSS parser, you might want to report it on [Github](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues), try applying styles using JavaScript natively as an alternative.

Comment: @Manoj I reported it on GitHub (https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/1424). I'll try later to apply the styles via JS.

Comment: @Manoj I just tried to use propertyEditorStyle properties "strokeColor" and "strokeWidth" and the border gets around the field and validation message, so that won't work for me.

Comment: Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: I can confirm that this issue does not happen on a real device. Tested on Samsung Galaxy A50 (SM-A505GT) running Android 10.

I'm using Genymtion and I tried in a new device (Google Nexus 5X with Android 7.1) and the issue also does not happen. It was happening in Google Nexus 5X with Android 5.1.

Comment: Can you provide the markup ?

Comment: @theFrontEndDev The markup is simply this: <RadDataForm ref="form" :source="data" :metadata="metadata"/>